# How is this question not on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[The Question in Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129961/taplinks-architecture)

Question was put on hold as perhaps being not on topic. I fail to see how asking for information about a (somewhat secretive) scheme that promises to (allegedly) solve all problems passwords have today not on topic here... there is even a tag for 'passwords' and one for 'salt', are all /those/ questions not on topic?

Comment: Why is this question, about the question in question, downvoted questionably?

Answer (score 4):

You have asked us to speculate on a commercial product's architecture. It's off topic because it is a question for the vendor.

Comment: It is no more off topic than asking about what an RFC really means. The vendor has been remarkably mum about their proposal, despite this requiring broad adoption to be effective.

Comment: It's off topic because we would have to speculate. As you say, the vendor is mum, and secretive. How would we be able to answer?

Comment: Taplink only makes sense with broad adoption, so the question is kinda necessary. And folks already turned up links to two talks, while I am asking for their (yet unpublished) whitepaper.

Comment: The question is necessary *if you want wide-spread adoption of the product* but off-topic here. There are lots of really good questions that simply don't fit here due to the nature of the forum.

Comment: I don't /want/ anything for their product, I just wish to understand what they are proposing. In effect, they are proposing a password standard - understanding it seems perfectly reasonable. Guess it isn't, who knows why.

Comment: @0xF2 you are confusing "reasonable question" with "on-topic question". Of course it is reasonable. It's just off-topic here because we can only speculate.

Comment: A lot of things are proprietary and require speculation. And yet they are not blanket all off-topic, are they?

Comment: @0xF2 pretty much, yes.